# Why does Safari keep adding a successively larger margin after each CSS page break?

Tags: css, printing, safari, webkit, fixed

I am trying to print a number of individual blocks in a single HTML page and breaking at the page boundary with "page-break-after:always". However each page printed has a slightly larger header margin applied. I have it down to the following test code that prints only "Hello World" and by page 145, it's a quarter down the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Printing Issue</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.break {
page-break-after:always;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
<div class="break"></div>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Load into Safari and use the print command and then "Preview" (open as PDF). Displaying the PDF thumbnails sidebar in Preview and scrolling to the last pages shows the "Hello World" having moved down the page. The issue presents itself exactly the same way when actually printing.

This is only an issue with WebKit based browsers. Any insight into fixing this issue in Safari is greatly appreciated.

**Update**: It's was a bug in WebKit that is now fixed in the latest nightly build "r103857". Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: i would report this as a bug in webkit.

Comment: Try using a CSS reset. Or browse around Google for a reset that is more specific to your problem.

Comment: This does not happen for me whatsoever. Safari 5.1.2.

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck: How would a CSS reset help?

Comment: @BoltClock It would help to ensure that the CSS is being rendered the same across all browsers. Same thing Josh Smith suggested.

Comment: Thank you everybody, a number of different CSS normalization/reset does not fix the issue. @Josh Smith Could you please send me a screenshot of page 145 to confirm that the bug does not happen on your system. I have tested it on 5 different computers (including Safari 5.1.2 build:7534.52.7) and get a consistent bug. I was about to submit a bug to WebKit, as Daniel suggested, but if you can confirm the opposite could you let me know more details about your system, it will help when submitting the bug to WebKit. Do you download the WebKit nightly build?

Comment: This bug is now fixed in the WebKit nightly. Thank you everybody for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You should [normalize your CSS](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) to avoid such problems.